# How to save an array of objects in localStorage? Getting TypeError: push is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to push player data (object) in an array, then save into `localStorage`, but I can't get it working even if I initialize the array. On the first run I got the data, but on the next runs the array is not recognised. Does anyone know what is going on? Here is my code:

```
  function handleRanking() {
    console.log('run function');
    let prevRanking = localStorage.getItem('ranking');
    if (prevRanking === null) {
      console.log('null value');
      prevRanking = [];
    }
    const player = {
      name,
      score: total,
      picture: gravatarEmail,
    };
    if (Array.isArray(prevRanking)) {
      prevRanking.push(JSON.stringify(player));
      localStorage.setItem('ranking', prevRanking);
    } else {
      console.log('not an array');
    }
  }
```

Comment: localStorage works with strings, you have to convert to and from JSON

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing to know right away is that `localStorage` can only save strings. Therefore when you want to save a non string value, you need to call `JSON.stringify(data)` before saving, and `JSON.parse(data)` after getting the data and before using it.

In your case, an easy way is to add the `player` and then save `prevRanking` as string. But before you should parse what you get as it is always a `string` if not `null`.

```js
  function handleRanking() {
    console.log('run function');
    let prevRanking = localStorage.getItem('ranking');
    if (prevRanking === null) {
      console.log('null value');
      prevRanking = [];
    }else{
     prevRanking = JSON.parse(prevRanking);
    }
    const player = {
      name,
      score: total,
      picture: gravatarEmail,
    };
    if (Array.isArray(prevRanking)) {
      prevRanking.push(player);
      localStorage.setItem('ranking', JSON.stringify(prevRanking));
    } else {
      console.log('not an array');
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

After you have retrieved the info from the localStorage you need to pass it into the `JSON.parse` method. Because when storing information in the localstorage it is saved as string.

```
function handleRanking() {
    console.log('run function');
    let prevRanking = localStorage.getItem('ranking');
    if (prevRanking === null) {
      console.log('null value');
      prevRanking = [];
    }
    prevRanking = JSON.parse(prevRanking); // added it in here so prevRanking is definetly defined
    const player = {
      name,
      score: total,
      picture: gravatarEmail,
    };
    if (Array.isArray(prevRanking)) {
      prevRanking.push(JSON.stringify(player));
      localStorage.setItem('ranking', JSON.stringify(prevRanking));
    } else {
      console.log('not an array');
    }
  }
```

Comment: It saves the player as object and even if I set player as an array, not working as well. Any other idea?

Comment: @KelsonBatista you also have to convert your prevRanking to a string when saving using JSON.stringify else you are storing something like: "[Object object], [Object object]" in the localstorage

Answer (score 0):

Because the value of a key gets from LocalStorage is a string. So, you have to JSON.parse before pushing.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/setItem#parameters